# How to return a sub-dataframe and append an extra row?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns, `start_time, end_time, quantity_start, quantity_end`. An example)

```
start_time end_time quantity_start quantity_end
0          10       0              1
10         20       1              3
20.        30       3              10
```

The `start_time` and `quantity_start` of the next row is always equal to the previous row's `end_time` and `quantity_end`.

I need to return a sub-dataframe that consists of only the `start_time` and `quantity_start`, but need to include an extra row accounting for the `quantity_end` associated with `end_time` for the last `end_time`.

So in the above case, the dataframe that needs to be returned should be:

```
start_time quantity_start
0          0              
10         1              
20.        3              
30         10
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = pd.lreshape(df, {'start_time': ['start_time', 'end_time'],
                       'quantity_start': ['quantity_start', 'quantity_end']}
                  ).drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   start_time  quantity_start
0           0               0
1          10               1
2          20               3
3          30              10
```

Comment: this method seems to check every `end_time, quantity_end` pair? In this case, we know it's just the last row that needs to be extracted

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it :

```
out = (
    df.melt(id_vars=["start_time", "end_time"])
           .drop(["variable", "end_time"], axis=1)
           .drop_duplicates(subset="value", keep="first")
           .rename(columns={"value": "quantity_start"})
           .reset_index(drop=True)
)

out.at[len(out)-1, "start_time"] = df.at[len(df)-1, "end_time"]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   start_time  quantity_start
0        0.00               0
1       10.00               1
2       20.00               3
5       30.00              10
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
row = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_time': df['end_time'].iat[-1],
    'quantity_start': df['quantity_end'].iat[-1]
}, index=[len(df)])

pd.concat([df, row]).filter(like='start')
```

Output:

```
   start_time  quantity_start
0           0               0
1          10               1
2          20               3
3          30              10
```